# Accessing HTML tags in a RUBY Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have the following code in my HTML.erb

```
<form>
   <input id="do" type="hidden" value="0" />
   <button type="submit" value="Next">SUBTRACT</button>
</form>
<form>
  <input id="do" type="hidden" value="1" />
  <button type="submit" value="Next" >ADD</button>
</form>
```

Now When I click the any of the 2 buttons, I want to check the value of the input id="do" inside my Ruby Controller. What would the syntax look like ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should optimally be separated into two actions in the controller where each of the forms would submit (using the `action` attribute).

```
<form action='add'>
   <input id="do" type="hidden" value="0" />
   <button type="submit" value="Next">SUBTRACT</button>
</form>
<form action='subtract'>
  <input id="do" type="hidden" value="1" />
  <button type="submit" value="Next" >ADD</button>
</form>

#in your controller
def add
  # do the addition processing
end

def subtract
  # do the subtraction processing
end
```

If you really need to implement them in 1 action, then you could use Rails `params` object.

Comment: I tried this, but when I click any button it redirects to a new URL itself.... localhost:3000/add. I have only one function in the controller : def index....where i have all my logic.

Comment: I don't think having only 1 action in the controller to handle all events is an optimal design. You'll need to separate them into as many actions as appropriate. I suggest you use Rails generators to have a blueprint/example of Rails actions and how it's using its RESTFUL actions. For the question at hand - you could define `add` and `subtract` and embed your logic there.

Comment: I understand your point, but the add and subtract action do not have a major impact as compared to others. It just changes a value of a ruby variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the name attributes, the name attributes get sent to the controller in the params hash

```
<form>
   <input id="do" name="subtract" type="hidden" value="0" />
   <button type="submit" value="Next">SUBTRACT</button>
</form>
<form>
  <input id="do" name="add" type="hidden" value="1" />
  <button type="submit" value="Next" >ADD</button>
</form>
```

In the controller,

the `params[:subtract]` or `params[:add]` will have the value depending on subtract clicked or add clicked .

Comment: How do I check the value of the input id="do" inside the ruby controller ?